# Get content (URL) from element and put it into jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I using `.load()` function to load content from another page. My page is `http://example.org/mypage.html`and contains this jQuery:

```
$(".content").load("http://example.org/12333.html .data");
```

How I can get this URL `http://example.org/12333.html` dynamically from another page: `http://example.org/static.html` to my jQuery code?

My static.html looks like:

```
<div class="link">
  <a href="http://example.org/12333.html">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I suppose you could run ` .load` on `static.html link` and `find` the first `a` with an `href`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this id "target" for another page.

```
$("#b" ).load( "article.html #target");
```